# React-Admin DateField, DateInput locale global

Tags: javascript, reactjs, localization, react-admin

React admin allows you to set Date locales at the component when you use the `DateField` and `DateInput`.

```
<DateField source="publication_date" locales="fr-FR" />
// renders the record { id: 1234, publication_date: new Date('2017-04-23') } as
<span>23/04/2017</span>
```

but most of the time we don't need to set it on the component, rather we need to configure it globally. Is there a way to set it globally?

I tried setting default `locale` of the i18n provider, but looks like it is only considered for translation and not for date formatting.

Also I tried overriding `Date.toLocaleDateString()` but didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the useLocale hook, which returns react-admin's i18nProvider current locale, which defaults to 'en'

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Translation.html#uselocale-getting-the-current-locale

Supposing this a Show view:

```
import { useLocale } from 'react-admin'

export const ResourceShow = props => {

    const locale = useLocale()

    return (
        <Show {...props}>
            <SimpleShowLayout>
                <DateField source="publication_date" locales={locale} />
            </SimpleShowLayout>
        </Show>
    )
}
```

And if you really wanna to override Date.toLocaleDateString, whice is not recommended, you can do so with:

```
Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString = customFunc
```

Btw, i agree that should be considered DateField use i18nProvider locale by default.